# Unit test: mock nested scala val

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I have two case class *A* and *AHelper*

```
case class AHelper(data: String) {
  def getData() = {...} // Complex operation inside
}

case class A(data1: String, data2: String) {
  private val aHelper = AHelper(data2)    // AHelper instance
  def getData() = {data1 + aHelper.getData; ...} // Complex operation inside
}
```

class *A* has instance of *AHelper* as one of its member.

I want to write unit tests for *A* only, mocking *AHelper*

Scala version: 2.11

Comment: In real scenario,  A and AHelper class, both are complex code

Comment: why can't you make A simple class? it will be easy

Comment: @RamanMishra Is making A simple class helps in solving this?

Comment: yes then you can override getData and return what ever you want just in the test case create a new object of A and override getData. Because anyway case classes are used for pattern matching we should avoid data function inside case class.

Comment: I don't want to override a.getData. I want to override aHelper.getData. a.getData in real case doing a lot more

Comment: I got your point but ultimately you are gonna assert on what ever is return by the A.getData? why not to override it and because anyway data1 will be available in object of A and if that can't be done make AHelper a simple class

Comment: first of all you don't need getData method, you can just get case class params just by using . I mean it seems java way of using scala.

Comment: Rather than overriding `getData`, why not make `val aHelper` protected and then override it in a subclass? That way you can use your fake helper without changing any other part of A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The helper should be a parameter:

```
case class A(data1: String, data2: String)(aHelper: AHelper = AHelper(data2))
```

Now in your tests, you can do: `A("foo", "bar")(mock[AHelper])`

If you don't like the second parameter list, there are a few options:

Make it implicit:

```
case class A(data1: String, data2: String)(implicit aHelper: AHelper = AHelper(data2))
```

This lets you create instances with just `new A("foo", "bar")` without having to tuck the `()` on the end

Or, create a companion object:

```
 object A {
   def apply(data1: String, data2: String): A = A(data1, data2)(AHelper(data2))
 }
```

*Note* also, that case classes with involved logic that require unit tests are ... unusual. Case class is meant to be just a dumb holder of the data, a tuple with named fields if you will. You should consider either splitting your logic out of these classes, or making them "regular" (non-case) classes instead.

For example:

```
case class A1(data: String)
case class A2(data1: String, data2: A1)

trait AHelper {
  def getData(a1: A1)
}

class  AReader(helper: AHelper) {
  def getData(a: A2) = a.data1 + helper.getData(a.data2))
}
```

Now, there are no questions how to properly test this, right?

Comment: thanks for explanation. I am new to scala. Give me sometime to understand companion object and other concept and I will return back to accept this answer

Comment: "case classes with involved logic that require unit tests are ... unusual" this is big statement for me. Is it you experience or general rule?

Comment: @user811602 it's both :)